# IBM Worklight 5.0.5 - How to view the notification_device table?

Tags: database, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have some issues working with push notification; I want to view the table NOTIFICATION_DEVICE where all the device information is stored.

How can I open this from Worklight server? Do I need to install any client for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Worklight Developer Edition by default is using the HSQL file-based database.
You can probably get somewhere on the web a .jar file to use in Eclipse to view it, but this is not a supported method by Worklight.

I would recommend to use MySQL as your database, and use a client to view its contents.

1. Install MySQL 5.1 or 5.5 (supported by Worklight 5)
2. Install some client, like SQLyog
3. Create a "Worklight" database
4. Create a "Worklight" username and password
5. Edit `server\conf\worklight.properties` to point to the database above as well as use the username and password
6. Add the MySQL Connector/J driver to `server\lib`
7. Do stuff in your app
8. Use SQLyog to view the database tables

Comment: Hi Idan, what if i want to open the derby default DB which comes with developer edition, can i view that one. please let me know.

Comment: If you find an Eclipse plug-in that will allow you to do that, sure. I don't know of such a plug-in.

Comment: @djrecker, if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.